# Exercise about wedge product and multilinear forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I'm considering $\omega\in \Lambda^{2q+1}(V^\ast)$, i.e. a multilinear skew-symmetric form.

I want to prove that $\omega\wedge\omega=0$.

How shall I proceed? Any suggestions?

Do I have to write $\omega$ as linear combination of $\epsilon_{i_1}\wedge\dots\epsilon_{i_q}$ first of all?

Do I loose generality if I suppose $\omega =\alpha \epsilon_{i_1}\wedge\dots\epsilon_{i_q}$?

Comment: This is true because $2q+1$ is an odd number; in general this is not true.

Comment: Grazie per la precisazione!

Comment: You are welcome! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much you need to do.  The wedge product satisfies the relationship:
$\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{pq} \beta \wedge \alpha$
if $\alpha, \beta \in \Lambda^p, \Lambda^q$ respectively.

In your case 
$$\omega \wedge \omega = (-1)^{(2q+1)(2q+1)} \omega \wedge \omega = -\omega \wedge \omega$$
That can only happen if $\omega \wedge \omega = 0$.

Comment: Why is there is $2q+1$ instead of $q$?

Comment: you don't know if $q$ is even or odd; and in the first case the statement is not true.

Comment: @avati91  I added in details.