# Some calculations with skew forms and wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I have some problems with the language of multilinear forms.

I have to prove that if $dim(V)\le 3$, then every $\omega\in\Lambda^q(V^\ast)$ is such that $\omega\wedge\omega=0$.

I consider the case $n:=dim(V)=3$.

I can write 
$$
\omega=\sum_{1\le i_1<\dots<i_q\le 3}\omega_{i_1\dots i_q}\epsilon_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge\epsilon_{i_q}=
\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<i_3\le 3}\omega_{i_1i_2i_3}\epsilon_{i_1}\wedge\epsilon_{i_2}\wedge\epsilon_{i_3}
$$
Then I make a lot of confusions because of the notation and I can't go on with the calculations. Any help?

Comment: Do I have to do all the calculations or can I make some assumptions (w.l.o.g.) to make things easier?

Comment: What does the result of your last question tell you?

Comment: The result of which question?

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1362069/39599).

Comment: I know! That in this case the result holds for $n=3$ in particular. But I'd like to be able to prove in via rough calculations as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As by the question linked by Michael, it is generally proved in a course about differential forms that $\alpha\wedge\beta = (-1)^{pq} \beta\wedge\alpha$ where $p$ and $q$ are the degrees of $\alpha$, $\beta$. Using this the result is immediate.

But you could try and prove it, at least in your specific case. Hint: it should not be difficult to prove it for basic 3-forms, that is 3-forms which are product of 1-forms, $\omega=\alpha\wedge\beta\wedge\gamma$, it is basically the definition of **skew** form. Now how does the general case follow from the one for basic 3-forms?

EDIT
I misread the question and my answer was partially incorrect.
If the degree of the form is odd the result holds generally (that is no matter what the dimension of the vector space $n$ is) and can be proved along the lines suggested above. If the degree is even the result generally does not hold. In fact it does not hold for 0-forms which are just constants. For 2-forms it holds, quite trivially because the space of 4-forms on a vector space of dimension 3 has dimension 0.

Comment: If I consider a basic form $\omega=\omega_{123}\epsilon_1\wedge\epsilon_2\wedge\epsilon_3$, then the result follows by using associativity of $\wedge$ and the property  $\epsilon_i\wedge\epsilon_i=0$. Then I think it's by linearity, but still I have to prove it

Comment: Actually if $n=3$, any $\omega\in\Lambda^q(V^\ast)$ is of the form $\omega=\omega_{123}\epsilon_1\wedge\epsilon_2\wedge\epsilon_3$. Right?

Comment: Yes, my answer was quite imprecise, see the edit. About 3-forms you are right there are no others, you can still use the hint for 1-forms though.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now things are much clearer